# Manually authenticate a Custom SAML2P message

Tags: c#, wif, saml-2.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, which uses WIF to authenticate users from various remote networks using WS-FED/SAML and Claims.

I have a new user group who wish to send me a custom SAML2-P POST message, which is essentially a Signed XML document within a custom XML document containing other unsigned meta-data.

WIF doesn't support SAML2-P messages, so I need to do this manually. I therefore need to:

1. Verify the SAML2-P message and SAML2 Assertions contained within.
2. Once verified, convert this into a ClaimsIdentity within ASP.NET MVC

I think I have figured out the first part, using the built in methods within the .Net framework.

I'm wonder about the best way to accomplish #2, and specifically where in the application to do this? Handler? Filter? etc?

Comment: I strongly advise against writing step #1 yourself. Use a library (e.g. https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) that's already solved all the signature wrapping exploits that can occur.

Comment: I've looked at the Kentor code base before, which will get me so far, but its a custom implementation, so I will have to cherry pick certain bits. The Saml2Response object seems to cover most bits.